# Ad hoc pushnotification is not working?

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications, ad-hoc-distribution

i develop new iphone application in which i make both certificate for him development and distribution.

i write my code for getting and register for APNS (push notification) it work fine with developer certificate but i didnot receive pushnotification when i signed application with distribution certificate.

i checked my distribution certificate it have  for production my bundle is correct.
i code signed correct with distribution certificate but not get push notification from gateway.push.apple.com 2195 port but same i got with gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com with developer certificate.

i tried too for create ipa file and sync but not get the notification with distribution certificate.

please guide me i need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing i can imagine, is that you are using the token generated from your app signed with dev certificate. You have 2 different token on the same device with dev and dist certificate.

Answer (score 6):

Currently your application is in development mode using devlopment provisioning profile so it will generate developer devicetoken which will work for devlopment push notification certificate

If you use adhoc distribution profile to make .ipa it will generate distribution device token which will work for distribution push notification certificate

So, **please use adhoc provisioning profile** to make .ipa.